# saveWebArchive() not working an Android 4.0.3

Tags: java, android, xml, android-webview, webarchive

I am trying to write a very simple code to save a web page to disk in a web archive in Android 4.0.3 ICS. My code is:

```
final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp");

Button forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bForward);
Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBack);
Button update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUpdate);

forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (myWebView.canGoForward())
            myWebView.goForward();
    }
});

back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack())
            myWebView.goBack();
        }
});

update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                    myWebView.saveWebArchive("theArch");                
    }
});
```

The thing is, the webview is working perfectly but whenever I am clicking the Update button, what I get is (from LogCat):

03-26 18:41:38.797: D/webcoreglue(755): saveWebArchive: Failed to initialize xml writer.

and nothing else happens whatsoever.....

Please can anyone help me out on this; as this is a component of something else very important....

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try providing a fully qualified path, not `"theArch"`. Use `getFilesDir()` and the `File` constructor to provide a path to internal storage, for example.

Comment: Works like a charm! I used myWebView.saveWebArchive(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "myArch"); and it did exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: thanks for your answer @CommonsWare but is there any alternative option for `saveWebArchive` as I also want to use below `Api 11`